# Как найти клиента с наибольшей суммой заказов в HashMap таблице?

Tags: java

Как правильно сделать вложенный цикл в методе getMaxOrderCustomerName(), чтобы найти клиента с наибольшей суммой заказов?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrdersManager ordersManager = new OrdersManager();

        ordersManager.printAllOrders();
        System.out.println("Всего заказов на сумму: " + ordersManager.getOrdersSum());

        String maxOrderCustomerName = ordersManager.getMaxOrderCustomerName();
        System.out.println("Самая большая сумма заказов у " + maxOrderCustomerName);
        ordersManager.printCustomerOrders(maxOrderCustomerName);

        ordersManager.removeUnprofitableOrders();
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class OrdersManager {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> customersOrders;

    public OrdersManager() {
        customersOrders = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Double> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(154.43);
        orders.add(5453.98);
        orders.add(8776.65);
        customersOrders.put("Иван И.", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(25343.54);
        orders.add(420.50);
        customersOrders.put("Ольга С.", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(325.90);
        customersOrders.put("Александр Т.", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(253.54);
        orders.add(420.50);
        customersOrders.put("Александр Р.", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(780.54);
        orders.add(420.50);
        orders.add(36343.54);
        orders.add(2000.50);
        customersOrders.put("Екатерина О.", orders);
    }

    void printAllOrders() {
        for (String name : customersOrders.keySet()) { // Цикл должен пройтись по ключам
            System.out.println("Заказы " + name + ":");
            ArrayList<Double> value = customersOrders.get(name);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

    double getOrdersSum() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Double> orders : customersOrders.values()) { // Здесь должен быть обход по значениям
            for (double orderPrice : orders) {
                sum += orderPrice;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    void printCustomerOrders(String customerName) {
        if (customersOrders.containsKey(customerName)) { // Проверьте, есть ли указанный ключ в таблице
            System.out.println("Заказы " + customerName + ":");
            System.out.println(customersOrders.get(customerName));
        }
    }

    String getMaxOrderCustomerName() {
        double maxOrder = 0;
        String customerName = "";

       // for (Double value : customersOrders.values()) {
       //     if (value > maxOrder) {
       //         maxOrder = value;
       //    }
       // } 

        return customerName;
    }

    void removeUnprofitableOrders() {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();// Создайте список клиентов с заказами меньше 5000​
        // Наполните список names
        for (String name : customersOrders.keySet()) {
            double ordersSum = 0;

            for (Double orders : customersOrders.get(name)) {
                ordersSum += orders;
            }
            if (ordersSum < 5000) {
                names.add(name);
            }
        }

        for (String name : names) {
            if (customersOrders.containsKey(name)) {
                customersOrders.remove(name);
                System.out.println("Клиента " + name + " больше нет в таблице.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ели просто добавить реализацию в ваш код, то примерно так:

```
String getMaxOrderCustomerName() {
    double maxOrder = 0;
    String customerName = "";
    for (String name : customersOrders.keySet()) {
        double order = customersOrders.get(name).stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
        if (maxOrder<order) customerName = name;
    }
    return customerName;
}
```

но в целом это вполне ужасно))

Comment: String getMaxOrderCustomerName() {
            double maxOrder = 0;
            String customerName = "";
        for (String name : customersOrders.keySet()) {    
            for (Double order : customersOrders.get(name)) {
            if (order > maxOrder){
                maxOrder = order;
                customerName = name;
                }
            }
        }
        return customerName;
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
String getMaxOrderCustomerName () { //Задача с курсов Яндекс.Практикум. На 04.2023 валидацию проходит.
    double maxOrder = 0;
    String customerName = "";
    for (String key : customersOrders.keySet ()) { // перебор списка ключей

        ArrayList <Double> ordersBuf = customersOrders.get (key); // получение значения одного ключа и сохранение его в промежуточный список

        Double summ = 0.0;
        for (Double order : ordersBuf) { // перебор всех значений из списка их суммирование
            summ += order;
        }

        if (summ > maxOrder) { // выбор наибольшей суммы и имени клиента, которому она принадлежит
            maxOrder = summ;
            customerName = key;
        }
    }
    return customerName;
}
```